# adding data into table from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am retrieving data from database and putting it on jtable, 11 items are coming from the database but only the 1st item is printed on jtable 11 times, I don't know where I am making mistake, i have used the loop variable in the statement so that it can be incremented automatically but its not working.

```
        try{

        java.util.Vector v=DatabaseManager.getGroceryItems(bean.getCategoryId());


        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

            GroceryItemsBean bean2=(GroceryItemsBean)v.elementAt(i);

                row.add(bean2.getItemId());
                row.add(bean2.getItemName());
                row.add(bean2.getBarcode());
                row.add(bean2.getStock());
                row.add(bean2.getPurchasePrice());
                row.add(bean2.getUnitPrice());
                row.add(bean2.getDisc());
                row.add(bean2.getTax());
                row.add(bean2.getUnit());

                dataModel.addRow(row);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "error: "+e.getMessage());
  }
```

[The output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmnb.png)

Comment: where and how is row defined?

Comment: row is the object of Vector class, this defined globally in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new "row" Vector for each row of data in the database:

```
GroceryItemsBean bean2=(GroceryItemsBean)v.elementAt(i);
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
```

Comment: Sir I have used your answer and that worked for me, now every record is printing on the table, but when I select a different item then that item comes on the table but the last item also comes, I have used stockTable.removeAll(); to remove everything from table before putting new item, but that is not working

Comment: You need to remove the data from the DefaultTableModel, not the JTable. You can use  `setRowCount(0)` to remove all the items from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see enough of your code but it looks like you  a new `row` object in the loop, otherwise it still has the values from the first iteration of the loop.

Or you should clear the row at the end of each iteration.

```
dataModel.addRow(row);
row.clear()
```